# I have Exited with error status 1 in python

Tags: python

I have this code and I get "Exited with error status one", can you help me find the error please?

```
n = int(input())
a = list(map(int, input().split(' ')[:n]))

for i in range(1, n, 1):
    if a[i] + a[i - 1] > 1:
        print("NU")
        exit(0)
print("DA")
```

Comment: Could you please describe what you code should do?

Comment: Likely, in one of your inputs you are not providing `int`-convertible strings on typing.

Comment: How do you run this code (shell, IDE, ...)? What is the **exact** error message? And what are the values you entered?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely that you get an exit code of 1 when you do not enter something that parses as integer. Then you will get an exception:

```
~$ python3 demo.py
A
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 1, in <module>
    n = int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'A'
~$ echo $?
1
~$
```

If you enter only integers in the correct format (you should print to your user that he needs to enter `n` numbers on the second input if he enters `n` on the first one) it works with an exit code of `0`:

```
~$ python3 demo.py
3
1 2 3
NU
~$
```

Look and read about exceptions in Python and how to handle them: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html